# PHP Includes and Load Time

Tags: php, include, admin, load-time

If I add PHP includes to a page.

```
include('example.php')
```

- It then has to load that file which would / could slow down load time correct? Right now I am making unnecessary redirects back to the a login page if the logins are wrong via javascript snippet that is inside my login.php page (which does all the login checking against the database). So in the address bar it shows "admin.php > login.php > admin.php" , but I don't ever want to show what file it is going to in order to test the logins, but I also do not want to include this inside admin.php because I'm afraid it might affect load time.

If you understand my question then suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Using an opcode cache like APC reduces the overhead of `include()`

Comment: apc is a caching addon you can install via pecl that does a couple of different things, one of which is to parse scripts into the php opcodes and store the cached script in shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New HTTP requests (redirects) are always a bigger performance hit than includes, so there's no reason to use redirects (especially Javascript ones) if you're only concerned about the performance. So if I understand you I'd like to suggest that you just include the file.

Comment: Gotcha, but what if the include is a bigger file, and do I need to worry about security issues via includes (such as making databse connections). Performance and Security are my biggest concerns. Having both seems to be fairly difficult :(

Comment: Big files are no problem for includes either. You have to think of it this way: when you include a file the code in the file is executed by the server and then appended to the HTTP request. When you separately call the file in a new request, the code is not only executed, but also a new request has to be created and the server has to route the request to the correct script. So it's no problem for bigger files either, using a separate request takes longer.

Comment: The same counts for security: you're essentially executing **the same** code, so if there's a vulnerability in the script it can be used either way. The only difference might be that by using a separate HTTP request the user can see more about how your site works, so in this case the include is also better. I have to say though that you shouldn't rely on this, since security through obscurity is just bad.

Comment: Finally, the only reason to use a separate request is, as JB Nizet pointed out below: readability and maintainability. If it's really easier for you, you should by all means use it, although I can't think of a situation where it is.

Comment: The main reason why I have my PHP in a seperate file (processing.php) is so I can wrap it around a (if($_POST)), which I wasn't sure I could do if I put it inside an include.

Comment: That's not a problem at all. You have to think of the `include()` function as a way to literally include code in your script: you just add code from an other file. You can put any code you like in that file. That also the reason it can be used for everything, but most people use it to organize their code and minimize duplicate code among scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Do what you feel is best in terms of readability and maintainability at server-side. Then, **if** you have a performance problem, find where it comes from by measuring (and not guessing), and try to optimize.

You're optimizing prematurely, and this is the root of all evil. Compared to the time it takes to a HTTP request/response to execute, including some additional lines of PHP is very certainly negligible.

Comment: Well it's not all about optimization, When I do not include - the address bar shows the "processing.php" before it actually redirects depending on the outcome. I do not want to show where the processing takes place but on the other hand I do not want to include a giant processing file, because then theoretically it would have to load "incude('processing.php') before it loads any HTML which would weigh on performance.

Comment: Why is your processing.php so huge? If it's because it contains many functions, then don't worry too much: PHP will only interpret the ones it needs to. As I said: architect your application so that it's readable and maintainable. Don't presuppose that you'll have a performance problem. There are pretty good chances that you're won't have any.